# Vertical Scrolling Bar Does not show when scrolling Android

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, scrollbar

some what new to android development. Currently, this is the code that I have for my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
tools:context="com.alibaba.weex.com.alibaba.app.WXPageActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollIndicators="right"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/index_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/index_progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="loading...."
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to get the vertical scroll bar to show? I've tried changing the all the framelayouts to relativelayouts, and then changing the second framelayout to a ScrollView, but the app crashes once I open it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your layout should be like this .

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/index_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/index_progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="loading...."
        android:visibility="gone" />

  </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You can't change scollview in the second framelayout because the scollview can only have one child .

Comment: Sorry, didnt work. Just end up getting a black screen, nothing loads